# Name for our customer's customer?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Trying to address a business domain where we are making software that will be used by our customers to give access to their assets to their customers.

What is a good name for these entities?

Is *client* a good name? But it's the same as *customer*?

Comment: As it's software 'end users' is prbably appropriate.

Comment: It sounds like the end user gets access to their assets through the cloud.  Therefore you could also say *site visitors*.

Comment: I strongly support *end user* in this case. But *second level* is also used in some contexts like this. You can have *second-level managers* (your boss's boss), so I imagine you could also have *second-level customers*.

Comment: It depends on point of view: if you're talking to your customers you could say "you and your customers", but talking to you it's "your customers and your customers' customers." This makes it hard to give a specific answer unless the situation is more specific (e.g. the three-level division between wholesalers, retailers, and private/individual/domestic customers).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There isn't such a word, but clientele can be used more gracefully in combination ("customer's clientele") than saying "customer's customer." It's one way to solve the problem.

> **clientele** *noun*
>   customers or clients collectively
>   <sub>[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/clientele)</sub>

Comment: *Clientele* doesn’t carry the sense the OP wants, of “customer’s customer”.

Comment: @Lawrence: There isn't such a word, but *clientele* can be used more gracefully in combination ("customer's clientele") than saying "customer's customer." It's one way to solve the problem.

Comment: I guess the comment explains your answer.  Why don't you put that in the answer?

Answer (score 2):

***end user***

> the person or organization that uses something rather than an organization that trades in it:

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/end-user)

...was the first thing I thought when I saw the Q, and as it turns out it was suggested in Jason Bassford's and BoldBen's comments below the OP.

Answer (score -1):

**Grand-customer**. It's like a grand-child, but it's not a child, it's a customer...

Your own customers are your direct Descendents.

Your customer's customers are their direct descendents, but it makes them one generation removed from you, thus grand-customers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is clever but I don't think the meaning is obvious without explanation - "grand" has too many other meanings and uses.